# Detect text add in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, addition, detect

I have a textarea in  my page. I click on the button "select country " a div appearre and i select my country. Onclick my country is add in textarea EX :

```
<textarea id="adresse_selection_relay" name="adresse_selection_relay">
**My Country**
</textarea>
```

I want disabled a submit button if the textarea is empty. The difficulty is the text are added on click.

I have try this :

```
var oldVal = "";
$("#adresse_selection_relay").on("change keyup paste cut", function() {
var currentVal = $(this).val();
if(currentVal == oldVal) {
return; //check to prevent multiple simultaneous triggers
}

oldVal = currentVal;
alert("changed!");
});
```

But offcourse my code don't work lol !
Thank's

Comment: Can't you attach an event listener to the "select country" button, or use a non-editable input of type text?

Comment: What is the purpose of all this? Maybe you should explain what you want to achieve. Might be better solutions then selecting from a div and adding to a textarea...

Answer (score 0):

Trt this.
No need to add your condition `if(currentVal == oldVal)`.
Onchange event will do it for you.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="adresse_selection_relay" name="adresse_selection_relay"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script>
 $('body').on('change', '#adresse_selection_relay', function() {

    /*
     //`No need to add this condition`
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    if(currentVal == oldVal) {
        return; //check to prevent multiple simultaneous triggers
    }   
    oldVal = currentVal; */

    alert("changed!");
});

</script>
```

Comment: In my order i have add un div. The di is open onclick i select an adresse Mondial relay. Onclick my adresse is add in the textarera, but i don't know how to enabled my button submit if they ahve an adresse in textarea.

Comment: Can you please add a complete HTML and Javascript code you had written to get an idea, what exactly you need...